# Why did Star Trek: Voyager end in this manner?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Perhaps it's only with the benefit of hindsight, but to me it seems that it would have been narratively natural to conclude *Star Trek: Voyager* with, say, a six-episode epilogue exploring the crew's return to friends and family, potential friction as Starfleet engineers start getting their grubby hands all over the interesting alien technology, possible back-and-forth Borg drama to close off the show's main storylines, and politics over the ship's future, possibly with a final nostalgia shot of her continuing service as part of the fleet in the Alpha Quadrant.

As we know, that didn't happen: the show instead ended abruptly with Voyager dropping out of a transwarp conduit near Earth, and a final shot of her being escorted by a few Starfleet ships, this widely being decried as an anti-climax.

Out of universe, has the production team ever given any evidence or inkling as to why it was decided to end the show in this manner? Was it deliberate? Or was it more accidental, perhaps shortcut-taking in the writers' room due to general fatigue or some other internal problems?

I realise that the premise of this question kind of assumes a particular subjective view on what the "best" ending might have looked like but, as I say, it does seem objectively natural to me to a degree, and I'm hardly the first to voice this view!

Comment: From googling I can see while many express disappointment, there's an extreme lack of consensus on why it was decided to be that way. From https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Endgame_(episode) we do know it was ended by choice, and it was decided early on to be a single two hour episode. I get the impression that there was no particular behind the scenes drama or anything like that, but simply that as is often the case with creative work, they weren't able to execute their ideas in a way the audience really liked.

Comment: A six part epilogue where we follow the crew through the difficulties they had returning to normal Starfleet procedures sounds awful. LOTR ending awful

Comment: @Valorum While I agree with that, I think the OP means they would like some closure. If well done, which is quite rare as you mention, some would find it interesting as well.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - I can only imagine what 7 years of incomplete paperwork looks like. That's what Janeway's first three months back looked like. Her sitting at a desk typing and signing.

Comment: The premise of the show was "A Starfleet vessel lost on the other side of the galaxy."  Once that's taken away, you lose half the viewers.  Or they just wanted to leave something for the books.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt I'm talking about an epilogue. I do not think the show would "lose half the viewers" because the ship wasn't in the Delta Quadrant until the last second.

Comment: The premise of Farscape was that John was lost on the other side of the universe. But he made it back to Earth briefly near the end, just in time to set up a "let's not bring all the trouble I've found, home with us" epilogue plot (which is kind of what I was thinking here).

Comment: The series needed a big finish, after which, everything else would be anti-climactic; the big finish was their arrival "home". They did do some set up (sprinkled through various episodes) about what could/would happen to various characters after they made it home, but to actually show it, anti-climactic. They did tie up a loose end with Neelix pretty close to the final episode. The Doctor's holonovel did in a way suggest his post-Delta Quadrant future. Ending the story in such an open way perhaps left the door open for other series built around other characters' subsequent exploits.

Comment: @AnthonyX I don't see why getting home six episodes before the end would necessarily be "anti-climatic" or rob the show of a "big finish". Think of the wealth of stories that could be told in that time. It could even end up with them having to go back to the Delta Quadrant, either permanently or only briefly. There are all sorts of ways to make a compelling and interesting story with a "big finish" that don't involve abruptly covering said big finish in ten seconds flat. _Most_ epics end with an epilogue.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica For an epic story, sure. Voyager was basically episodic. Although they had recurring antagonists like the Borg, Kazon, Vidiians, and Hirogen, there were a few two-part episodes, and at least a few characters enjoyed character arcs, there weren't any epic story arcs beyond "lost in the Delta Quadrant, found a way home". In the same way as the premiere set up the premise of the show, the finale book-ended it; what came in between was essentially episodic, barring season to season tweaks and cast changes, so the finale had to fit within 1-2 episodes.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Perhaps another way to look at it: every episode starts and/or ends with Voyager in the Delta Quadrant; that's the core premise of the show - they are in the Delta Quadrant. The premiere shows how they got there. Once they arrive "home", the show's core premise is gone... unless, like the Gilligan's Island reunion show, they arrive home, only to end up right back in the Delta Quadrant again.

Comment: @AnthonyX Half the premiere was in the Alpha Quadrant. Why couldn't half the finale be in the Delta Quadrant? I don't really find the "premise" argument to be too compelling. The premise of Breaking Bad was two geysers making meth together. That doesn't mean they _had_ to do it every single episode right up to the end, as the showrunners were clearly aware. Almost every other show I can think of wasn't a slave to their premise; indeed, the level of adherence to original premise is a _consequence_ of the stories you choose to tell, not a strict constraint on _what_ stories you can tell.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Actually, the two-part finale actually begins ten years after Voyager has returned, following 23 years in the Delta Quadrant. We see how many of the characters have spent their lives following the ship's return, setting up Janeway's motive to break a bunch of rules, mess with the timeline, and bring them home sooner. A good portion of part 1 is spent in the "original timeline" future (intercut with the timeframe Janeway journeys back to). Nevertheless, Voyager isn't "Voyager" without Voyager; post-return, ship and crew are no longer cohesive i.e. no longer "Voyager".

Comment: @AnthonyX I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. We're kind of off topic anyway as this isn't the producers' rationale (unless it is!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101197/discussion-between-anthony-x-and-lightness-races-with-monica).

Comment: Answer not satisfactory?

Comment: @desertnaut It's great, thank you. I upvoted it. I don't accept after just a day, though - let's wait and see what else happens! Cheers.

Comment: Hi. Any chance of accepting the answer, 2 months after the question was asked? Cheers...

Comment: One word: [AfterMASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AfterMASH).

Answer (score 22):

Before attempting to answer, let me admit that the question seems to me to have indeed a high degree of subjectivity (e.g., it is not clear why specifically a *six*-episode epilogue is discussed as a possible alternative choice), something that you already seem to recognize ("*this question kind of assumes a particular subjective view*"). Nevertheless, I will try to shed some light in the decisions that led to the finale, quoting from the oral histories included in the relevant chapter of the 2016 book by Mark A. Altman & Edward Gross, [*The Fifty-Year Mission: The Next 25 Years - From The Next Generation to J. J. Abrams*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1250089468).

To start with, and although *Voyager* admittedly had a highly episodic (as opposed to serialized) structure, it seems that this characteristic was somewhat relaxed for the last season; here is executive producer Kenneth Biller, shining also some light into *why* such an episodic structure had been the choice until then in the first place:

> Rick Berman and the studio basically said to me, "Okay, this is the last season and whoever's watching the show in the seventh season are people who are already invested in the show and characters." They allowed me to take a more serialized approach in the final season. So we did storylines [...] And the quest to get home got played out in a more serialized way than it had been in previous seasons. The lack of serialization before wasn't really driven by the creative desires of the writers or the cast, but driven by the economic realities or at least the *perceived* economic realities of the long-term health of the show and the ability to show it in repeats and to foreign viewers.
>
> [...] as I said, I wanted to make that last season as serialized  as I possibly could, even within the framework of the stand-alone episodes.

Given the existing pre-occupation with the episodic structure, the "*more serialized approach*" mentioned here by Biller arguably did not go as far as a six-episode arc (after returning home or otherwise), neither it was supposed to. In fact, it already seemed rather too-little-too-late; here is actor Robert Beltran (Chakotay), commenting on "*the Chakotay/Seven of Nine thing that came up*":

> So they just kind of threw us together and it seemed to me that if they had been thinking instead of one episode after the other, but thinking in the long run, what great stuff they could have written preparing for that.

According to the oral histories preserved in the book, everybody seems to agree that *a lot* of things and ideas were considered for the finale, including killing Janeway and/or Seven of Nine; but (and here you have to take my word for it, as I obviously cannot quote the whole chapter), there is not the *slightest* indication that something in the lines of *let's bring them back before the show's end, proceed to show how well or not they manage to adapt, and then finish there* was ever considered.

In fact, the most direct (although still not explicit) testimony that something like that could not have happened even as a thought, comes from Rick Berman himself, and, rather unsurprisingly, it has to do with the very essence of *Voyager*:

> It was a great idea to go in the direction we did with the show, but at the same time there's something about venturing outward and trying to get back home that are diametrically different from one another. *Star Trek* by and large is a show about exploration, and exploration is going forth, it's not trying to find your way home.

... *let alone what you do **after** you are back home*, we can arguably hear him saying, although not explicitly...